# Angularjs & node best way to store route and post changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

What is the best way to send a request to the server on every time a angularjs client route changes ( angular to node)?

I'm thinking about how I would store what page the user is visiting . What would be the best approach  without any heavily load ?

I'm also thinking about logging every post requests sent to the server , so see what kind of requests , clicks and info about what the user is currently doing .  What would be the best approach to do so without making any heavy load to the server ?

For information  I'm using mean stack . And the plan is to store everything in the database .

Edit :

I will use onchange route events and server sided middleware

But what would the best way to do those be without any heavy load ?

Comment: why not use google analytics? No need to create a db or UI to read all of it that way and it's free

Comment: I need to know whenever the user navigates around the page , what button and actions they do , and when . For each user . I need it to control them . Because it's a game .

Comment: well you already know when post requests are made ... that part is easy ... and routers have route change events that can trigger a server request

Comment: if you need close interaction with it then set up socket connections. Without a lot more specifics this question is far too broad

Comment: still very vague ... what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I use these events to trigger console logs in my angular app, in your case you could use the below $stateChangeSuccess event. There are other events as well:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      console.log('$stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition.');
      console.log(arguments);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      console.log('$stateChangeSuccess to '+toState.name+'- fired once the state transition is complete.');
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(event){
      console.log('$viewContentLoaded - fired after dom rendered',event);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
      console.log('$stateNotFound '+unfoundState.to+'  - fired when a state cannot be found by its name.');
      console.log(unfoundState, fromState, fromParams);
    });
}
```